# Problem with object oriented programming in Java

Tags: java, oop

So I would like to start out by telling you that I am learning Java on my own and you guys are the nearest thing I have to teachers. So thank you so much for putting up with my simple and obvious question. I am just trying to learn. Once again I am getting an error that for the life of me I cannot figure out.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Advisor_score.All_user.Score1(All_user.java:13)
at Advisor_score.All_user.main(All_user.java:28)
```

Here is my code for the ratings class:

```
package Advisor_score;
public class Rating {
    double [] Ratings;
    double sum=0;
    double raw_advisor;
    double advisor_score;
public Rating (double [] x){
        Ratings = x;
        }

public double Score(){
for(int i=2;i<Ratings.length;i++){
    sum+=Ratings[i];
}
raw_advisor=((sum-(3*(Ratings.length-2)))/4);
advisor_score= 2.5+(2.5*(1-Math.pow(Math.E, -.5*raw_advisor)));
return advisor_score;
}
```

Here is my code for the other class:

```
package Advisor_score;      

public class All_user{
        double [] ADVISOR_SCORE;
        Rating [] All_users;
        double score;
        public All_user(Rating...args){
                All_users=args;
            }

        public double [] Score1(){
            for (int j = 0;j<All_users.length;j++){
                score=All_users[j].Score();
                ADVISOR_SCORE[j]=score;
                }
            return ADVISOR_SCORE;
        }
        public void print(){
            for(int i = 0;i<ADVISOR_SCORE.length;i++){
            System.out.println(ADVISOR_SCORE[i]);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){ 
            double p1_1[] = {101,1,5,5,5};
            double p2_1[] = {101,1,1,2,3};
            Rating d = new Rating(p1_1);
            Rating e = new Rating(p2_1);
            All_user all=new All_user(d, e);
            all.Score1();
            all.print();
        }

    }
```

Again, I cannot thank you guys enough at StackOverflow. Your help has been invaluable!!

Comment: I'd also like to give you some advice - Use List instead of arrays;  Follow java naming conventions; embrace the for each loop construct.

Comment: Followup to Robert's comment, here is a link to the standard Java conventions, which will help your Java code look more like Java.  :)   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have not initialized the ADVISOR_SCORE and All_users arrays, but you do try to assign values and use them. When you declare

```
double[] ADVISOR_SCORE; // this is null until assigned
```

At some point, it needs to be assigned

```
ADVISOR_SCORE = new double[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

this variable:

```
double [] ADVISOR_SCORE;
```

hasn't been initialized... and therefore it's `null`.

Answer (score 1):

ADVISOR_SCORE has not been initialised

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Storey provided the best explanation, here are two semi-related tips I had to learn when learning Java:

1) Once you initialize that array

```
ADVISOR_SCORE = new double[size];
```

You cannot modify the array's length unless you re-initialize it.  Students often will try to add another value onto the end of an array or otherwise "grow" it somehow.  If this is something you need, checkout [Vector](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and [ArrayList](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

2) Java coding conventions are to capitalize class names...

```
public class Rating {
```

...but leave the first letter of method names in lower case.

```
public double [] getFirstScore() {
```

It'll help readability when others start working on your code.

Happy coding!